# Two columns table : one as small as possible, the other takes the rest

Tags: html, css, html-table, autosize

I have a to-columns table in a div :

```
<div>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="action" >
        <a> ✔ </a>
      </td>
      <td class="content">
       <p>Bigger text...(variable size).......</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="action" >
        <a> ✔ </a><a> ✘ </a>
      </td>
      <td class="content">
       <p>Bigger text...(variable size).......</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
      ... same structure in all the table
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

And I would like the "action" column to fit the content, and the "content" column to take the rest of available space. The "action" column would look better with a right align.
The table should also fit 100% of the container's width.

Is there a way of doing this without fixing the columns width ?

I tried with this:

```
table .action
{
    width:auto;
    text-align:right;
}
table 
{
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border-spacing:0;
    width:100%;
}
```

But the left column takes half of the table...

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Giving the content `td` a 100% width will force it to take as much space as it can, so `.content{ width: 100% }` should work.

Also give the .action a `white-space: nowrap` to make sure the x and the checkmark stay next to each other. Otherwise the content will be able to take even more space and force the icons below each other.

```css
table .action
{
    width:auto;
    text-align:right;
    white-space: nowrap
}
table .content { 
    width: 100% 
}
table 
{
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border-spacing:0;
    width:100%;
    border: 1px solid
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="action" >
        <a> ✔ </a>
      </td>
      <td class="content">
       <p>Bigger text...(variable size).......</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="action" >
        <a> ✔ </a><a> ✘ </a>
      </td>
      <td class="content">
       <p>Bigger text...(variable size).......</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: is there a way to do the same without tables but div's instead?

Comment: Sure, just use the `display: table-cell` property (maybe also `display: table-row` on the div around them) and they should behave just like a table

Answer (score 35):

Set the column `width: 1px` and `white-space: nowrap`.

This will try to make it 1px, but the nowrap will stop it from getting smaller than the widest element in that column.

Comment: Right now (2021), setting the width to 0 works better.

Answer (score 16):

I found this answer when trying to make one column of many **as small as possible**.

Giving the content `td` a 1% `width` will force it to take as little space as it can, so `.content{ width: 1% }` worked for me.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think it doesn't fit the requirements: the column should be as small as possible, but the content should be visible. Looks like with a 1% or 1px column, it wouldn't work.

Comment: I think the problem is that you say to make the content column 1% when it should have been the action column. I think your idea is sound, you just mixed it up, though that shouldn't warrant a downvote, but merely a correction. The one advantage of your method is that I think it would handle certain situations better. If there are 2 columns, then the accepted 100% answer works. But what if there are 4 columns, and you want the first 3 to automatically adjust their widths accordingly, but the 4th column should be as small as possible. In that case, your 1% works, where the 100% won't.

Comment: Also, you didn't account for the 2 icons, which you almost surely want side by side, not one above the other, so you'd need to do the nowrap (like the accepted answer)

Comment: I also needed columns to take up as little horizontal space as possible. They contained either an orderindex, checkbox, or button. I started with this answer, width: 1%, but I enhanced it with adding the white-space: nowrap; to my class. This appears to work well on Chrome, IE.

Answer (score 0):

The bootstrapian way of doing this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-1"> content... </div>
    <div class="col"> content... </div>
</div>
```

Basically you need to try out different things keeping in mind the following:

- `col-sm` Small column
- `col-sm-1` Smallest column
- `col-sm-2` Slightly bigger than smallest column (Numbers go from 1 to 12)
- `col-md` Medium sized columns (same numbering rule)
- `col-lg` Large sized columns (same numbering rule)